# Combining SUMIF and SUMPRODUCT statements

Tags: excel-2010

I have two separate formulas that work, but I’m having trouble combining them.

```
A       B
Alex    50000
Alex    200000
John    50000
```

I want to sum the values in column B for numbers that are equal to and greater than 50000 but less than 100000 only for where Alex appears in column A.

=SUMIF(A2:A4,"Alex",B2:B4)
=SUMPRODUCT((B2:B4>=50000)*(B2:B4<100000),B2:B4)

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This only requires `SUMPRODUCT`.

Just always maintain the pattern:

```
SUMPRODUCT(
  (ConditionRange1=Condition1)*
  (ConditionRange2=Condition2)*
  (ConditionRange3=Condition3)*
  (ValueRange))
```

So, in your example:

```
  SUMPRODUCT(
    (B2:B4>=50000)*
    (B2:B4<100000)*
    (A2:A4="Alex")*
    (B2:B4))
```

`SUMPRODUCT` will now evaluate the conditions of every row with either `0` or `1`, take the product per row and sum it up. (And if theres one time `0`, the row results in `0`, which does not Change the final sum):

```
A       B       >=50000   < 100000  "Alex"  RowProduct
Alex    50000   1         1         1       1*1*1*50000  = 50000
Alex    200000  1         0         1       1*0*1*200000 = 0
John    50000   1         1         0       1*1*0*50000  = 0
                                                        --------
                                                           50000
```

Comment: @FraserDean you're welcome. The SumProduct is really powerfull, when it Comes down to lookups with mutliple conditions.